# Is TMUX646 suitable for 10 input signals in parallel?

Tags: multiplexer

I'm trying to determine whether the [TMUX646](https://www.ti.com/product/de-de/TMUX646) matches my needs.In the data sheet it is written: *The TMUX646 is an optimized 10-channel (5 differential) single-pole, double-throw bi-directional switch for use in high speed applications. The TMUX646 is a high-speed 4 data lane 2:1 MIPI Switch. The device includes 10 channels (5 differential) with 4 differential data lanes and 1 differential clock lane for D-PHY, CSI or DSI.*

And here is the block diagram:
[image: img]

Basically, I don't know whether I can only switch between a set of pins A and B? Or whether I can really use 10 input signals in parallel which go to 10 output signals.

Comment: This device has 10 channels in parallel. You have not told us what your actual requirements are; 10 inputs going to 10 outputs can be implemented with 10 pieces of wire.

Comment: Thank you! I will use this multiplexer actually only as an on-off switch.

Comment: btw, only for my understanding: I've seen that the 10 pins are actually 5 differential channels. Could one use them as ten independent signal lanes nonetheless, or is a differential usage mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

The TMUX646 is a 2:1 switch with a bandwidth of 6 GHz; this is probably overkill. (And it comes only in a BGA package.)

For an on/off switch, you do not need a multiplexer. There are much simpler 10-channel or 16-channel 1:1 switches (e.g., SN74CBTLV3861).

Comment: thank you, this looks indeed better.